# Extract Text Between Two / Characters

Tags: sql, regex

From this URL http://go.example.edu/testrecord/landing

I am trying to extract the text: testrecord

IF the URL contains"goapp.ly", I want to extract: testrecord

Example URL: https://testrecord.goapp.ly/example/landing

The formula I have so far is:

REGEXP_EXTRACT(Hostname,"^(.+).")

However, all I am getting from that is testrecord.goapp.l

How can I ensure I only extract the text testrecord provided that both URLs may happen?

Comment: Try `REGEXP_REPLACE(Hostname, '^.*?//([^.]*)\.goapp\.ly.*|^.*/([^/]+)/.*', '\1\2')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what database you are using, but perhaps this will do what you want:

```
select regexp_extract('http://go.example.edu/testrecord/landing', '[^/]+',  4)
```

The "4" means to get the fourth time the pattern appears.